# How values from one HTTP get request are used as @QueryParams in another get request in Google Guice?

Tags: java, http, request, get, guice

I am having problem with understanding how exactly multiple HTTP get requests work together. Let's say I have a GET request which returns a collection of CustomObjects according to a given id.

```java
class CustomObject {
    private final Integer code;
}
```

CustomObject has other fields inside but they are not related to the task.

```java
@GET
@Path("/{id}/testPoint")
public Collection<CustomObject> getCustomObject(@PathParam("id") int objectId) {
    // ...
}
```

And I have another GET request which is called after this one.

```java
@GET
@Path("/{id}/calculateSmth")
public CustomCalculations getCalculations (@PathParam("id") int id,......,  @QueryParam("code") Integer code
```

And actually I don't get how this 'code' is getting passed to the second GET request because the first request returns it and the second uses it but it does not have explicit call inside,  I don't get how things are getting passed around.
All data is taken from database.

I am having trouble understanding how things are passed across multiple GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your title has the question:

> How values from one HTTP get request are used as @QueryParams in another get request in Google Guice?

But @QueryParam is a JAX-RS annotation. You need a REST-API implementation tool to handle those, which Google's Guice is not.

Google's Guice is a Dependency Injection tool. It theoretically has nothing to do with a HTTP request. However! Guice does have some utility to scope dependency injections to an HTTP request, so it can confuse people like it may have done here for you. BUT do not mistake Guice as an API tool.

> I am having problem with understanding how exactly multiple HTTP get requests work together...And actually I don't get how this 'code' is getting passed to the second GET request because the first request returns it and the second uses it but it does not have explicit call inside.

This is a separate question, but I'd answer it by saying your intuition is correct. It doesn't pass the two pieces together magically.

Either your HTTP client is saving the request of the first call and passing it into the second call, or you are receiving nulls as your second parameter, and possibly still setting it via a new DB lookup.

Several linting tools suggest treating HTTP parameter fields as final to avoid confusion like this.

Perhaps your code looks like this, which would be why you're confused. Note: this is not advice on how to change your code.

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}/calculateSmth")
public CustomCalculations getCalculations (@PathParam("id") int id, ..., @QueryParam("code") Integer code) {
    if (code == null) {
        code = db.lookup(id).getCode();
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask further questions, but please consider upvoting this as an answer to your initial question.